# Value of Sums of Partial Products of Polynomial Roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, roots

Take a general polynomial over the reals: $ax^n+bx^{n-1}+...+z$. Then it is known that for the sum of the roots,

$\sum_i a_i=-b/a$,

and for the product of the roots,

$\prod_i a_i=\pm z/a$,

depending on whether the polynomial is even or odd. Is there a known value based on the coefficients of the polynomial for the sums of partial products of roots:

$\sum_{i\neq j} a_ia_j$,

$\sum_{i\neq j, j\neq k, k\neq i} a_ia_ka_j$,

etc?

Comment: You may want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: Or, to reinvent Vieta's formulas, write the polynomial as $\,a \prod_i (x-a_i)\,$ and identify the coefficients.